# unordered_map identity by memory

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

The following example has a runtime exception in the `at` function.
How else can I check for identity?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Data {
public:
    bool operator==(const Data& other) const
    {
        return this == &other;
    }

    struct DataHasher
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Data& other) const
        {
            return 0;
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<Data, Data, Data::DataHasher> map;
    Data data1;
    Data data2;
    map[data1] = data2;
    map.at(data1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it your intention to create `Data` such that a copy is not equal to itself?  There is no "identity" if no two instances are the same.

Comment: standard containers own their elements.  That means the map has a data object in it, and that can never have the same address as the data object from `main`. What are you actually trying to solve?  Shouldn't `Data` hold some sort of data you can use for comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is explicit about what is an object (that is, a value) and what is a reference to one. If object identity is what interests you, you should use pointers, whose value is the address (and thus identity) of another object:

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<Data *, Data *> map;
    Data data1;
    Data data2;
    map[&data1] = &data2;
    map.at(&data1);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't need to tamper with any equality or hashing operation, as pointers already have those.

Of course, you'll need to ensure that the actual `Data` objects outlive the map so the pointers aren't invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying doesn't work because your map element is a distinct copy of `data1` and thus doesn't have the same address and thus the lookup doesn't find `data1` from the map.

Looks like you want to be storing pointers in the map.